# Git: Host Key Verification Failed

Tags: html, git, github

I am Trying to make a commit to my repository but when i click on Publish Branch then an error occurs please help me guys I need help with office work and I am new.

[Click Here to check the Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7ike.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+Host+Key+Verification+Failed

Answer (score 1):

There are two solutions for this:

Switch the remote URL to use HTTPS instead of SSH (you should not have any authentication issues as long as you are logged in with your GitHub account in GitHub Desktop).

Get SSH working. The host key verification failed error means that the host key from GitHub Enterprise isn't in your known_hosts file. You should be able to fix this by running the following command from Git Bash:

```
ssh-keyscan -H <GitHub_URL> >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```